# Using home address when submitting an article with no affiliation?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, independent-researcher

If you're submitting information for an article, and you have no institution affiliation, what should you use? I was asked for an address and all I have is an home address. That seems a bit weird to use, however.

Comment: In what way did they ask for this address, and in what way will it be used? For example, did they ask for it explicitly in an email, is it just part of their article template, or was it in a web form? Will it appear in the PDF of your publication? (Look at other papers published in this journal to find out.)

Comment: It's nature communications, so it looks like it will be. I'm not actually the corresponding author, so I'm not sure on the exact details. I was just asked to provide an address, including a home address if necessary. To add to the weirdness, I've moved since submitting, and I'm about to move again.

Comment: _I'm about to move again_ Do you already know your future location? I am not asking the actual future address.

Comment: It's actually in the same city.

Comment: Perhaps an email address would be the most useful thing to give, especially given your transience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did a quick search to see what other independent researchers do for Nature journals, which include an author address.Specifically, I searched Google for

> site:nature.com "author details" "independent researcher"

I found that authors who are independent researchers sometimes list just their city for their address, or

> Independent researcher, City, Country

See for example [here](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep10432#author-information) and [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v487/n7408/full/487432e.html#author-information). Some do appear to give their home address, e.g. [here](http://www.nature.com/nclimate/journal/v4/n10/full/nclimate2373.html#author-information) and [here](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep17556#author-information).

Comment: Awesome, it maybe too late to change this one. It's been submitted, and I didn't realise the corresponding author had my entire address, or that it would be displayed.

Comment: @user41824 submitted at what stage? I'm not familiar with the specific journal, but usually you can make changes up until the proofs stage - see [typical workflow of a journal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

Comment: I'll ask, it's just an odd place to be when you're not the corresponding author, and you're not affiliated with him

Comment: I am the co-corresponding independent researcher on the first linked paper in this answer. Here my case: I help my wife with her lab without _formal_ affiliation. Full home address felt weird to me. Lab address felt wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Based on some previous answers, it seems that you may pay a price for not having a university affiliation. But what are you going to do? Invent an address? Maybe you could create a consulting company (which should be registered if you ever plan to derive any income from it). That line of "ClearBlue Solutions" thrown into your home address may just do the trick.

Comment: How do you mean 'pay a price'? I'll use it, but it seems odd, esp since I'm moving.