# Is it fine to use a startup as an affiliation?

Tags: publications, independent-researcher, affiliation

My situation: I have finished university more than 10 years ago. I work for company X. I also own a small startup company called Y (no employees). I am in the process of publishing a paper and I was asked to provide an affiliation. Not providing one is not an option, in the sense it's a mandatory field on the form. I asked X and X said no, as I worked on the paper in my spare time.

Does it make sense to use Y as my affiliation (which is 100% true though not necessarily relevant)? The other option would be to try with something like "Independent researcher" and hope the journal is fine with it ([idea came from here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/what-to-put-in-affiliation-field-when-submitting-paper-without-affiliation); [example](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep10432#author-information)).

Relevant questions:

1. [Does one need to be affiliated with a university to publish papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers)
2. [Using home address when submitting an article with no affiliation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60082/using-home-address-when-submitting-an-article-with-no-affiliation)

Comment: Yes it's fine. I think the questions you linked answer this one.

Comment: Note ... the address you include in the paper should be somewhere you can be contacted in the future.  Perhaps years in the future.

Comment: @GEdgar that's a good idea in principle, but in practice a significant fraction of scientists are postdocs or PhD students with short-term contracts and no idea where they will be in 3 years.

Comment: @GEdgar There's been no mention of an address

Comment: There was a guy, who noted the address of a jail as an address for correspondence in a research paper. If an in-mate can do this and it's obviously Ok, you are fine anyway.

Comment: i can't recall details, but there is a high-profile author of peer-reviewed papers, who has his backyard shed as an affiliation

Answer (score 4):

> I was asked to provide an affiliation [for a paper]. Not providing one is not an option, in the sense it's a mandatory field on the form.

You could write *N/A* or *unaffiliated*, since this seems like the most relevant answer.

> Does it make sense to use [my startup] as my affiliation (which is 100% true though not necessarily relevant)?

Just like your employer decided that they didn't want their company name on your paper, you should consider whether you want your startup name on your paper.

---

<sup>On an aside, I wonder whether an employer (generally) has the right to deny an employee of listing the employer as their affiliation. (Some employers -- especially those in R&D -- will explicitly define contractual conditions, but generally they will not.)</sup>

Comment: Extrapolating from that an employer can "set free" an invention the employee makes (at least that's how things work over here in Germany), I'd think they should be able to do the same with a paper.

Comment: @cbeleites An employer can make many things happen, but I'd like to consider the general case. (To my knowledge, inventions are always owned by inventors, not employers. But, contractual clauses can be defined to enable sale of inventions to employers.)

Comment: that depends a lot on legislation. Here in Germany, this is the general case in the sense that the legal default for both inventions and copyright-relevant IP is that as soon as it is relevant to the employer's business, it is theirs to exploit (including software written in the employee's free time!). The employment contract can assign these rights to the employee (highly non-standard), or the employer can declare on a case-by-case basis they don't want it. (In case of inventions: 3 weeks to decide) And there has to be fair compensation...

Comment: ...  But if the employer says they don't want to have anything to do with it, I don't see how the employer can be affiliation for the paper. The fact that the inventor/author will always stay inventor/author is "bound" to the person, not to their employer in any case.

Comment: @cbeleites an employer might say "they don't want to have anything to do with it," but I'm unsure whether they'd have the right. For example, can an employer forbid an employee from listing the employer as such? On their LinkedIn profile, for instance. (Contractual) exceptions exist, e.g., some government employees, but what's the default? An author's affiliation is typically their employer. What rights do employers have to forbid employees stating their employer? (OT.The German system seems sensible: inventions are owned by inventors and sold to employers (if they want), in the default case.)

Comment: I'd think that to forbid stating the mere fact of employment (linkedin, CV, ...) the employer would need to show *very* good reasons (and BTW, over here employees have right to get a certificate of their working performance from the employer [which we use instead of letters of recommendation] and that anyways states who the employer is). But IMHO a paper affiliation signals more than the mere employment relationship, I'd say it means that the employee did that work on behalf of the employer, and that the employer agrees with the content. And while the question here doesn't look like a heavy...

Comment: ...disagreement, IMHO in the extreme case of disagreement about the (scientific) content of the publication the employer should have the right to not be associated with the project. I.e., as a coauthor, I can solve such disagreements by saying "Let's agree to disagree, you go ahead with the paper, but please, I'd like to *not* be associated with it in any way". The other authors would not have the right to put me on the coauthor list in that case. I see the affiliation question in analogy to that.

Comment: @cbeleites Should "a paper affiliation [signal] more than the mere employment relationship"? I've seen journalists explicitly disconnect the role of affiliations, e.g., by explicitly stating the author may have conducted the research independently of their employer. I've also seen authors make such explicit disconnections. Moreover, it is common to list a current employer, even when the work was conducted under a different employer (an acknowledgement to the previous employer might be included).

Comment: I've asked a question how much of a connection between paper and institution an affiliation implies: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117429/what-does-affiliation-for-a-publication-signify

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the actual subject of your paper has nothing to do with your work on startup Y. In that case, I think it‘s more accurate to report your affiliation as “independent researcher”, “no affiliation”, or “N/A”. Readers of the journal simply aren’t going to care about your connection to the startup in a completely unrelated context; why distract them with irrelevant information?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Y as my affiliation just to advertise my startup (this reason was not mentioned in the other answers).

I think readers do not care one way or another what the affiliation is - I certainly don't. No need to overthink this, it is also fine to add Independent researcher or No affiliation.

Comment: Using Y for advertising might backfire, as I mentioned "Just like your employer decided that they didn't want their company name on your paper, you should consider whether you want your startup name on your paper."

Comment: @user2768 What specific form will the backfiring take? Would some reader of the paper think less of the firm Y because it is the author's affiliation? Will someone Googling for firm Y and finding it as an affiliation on the paper think negatively of Y?

Comment: Numerous backfires are possible. One backfire tied to this particular instance is that readers might question why the startup owner is working on something completely irrelevant to the startup. Company owners should consider what they want associated with their name and only associate such material.